# Организовать для или кому?

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как правильно написать предложение: "Организовать завтраки и обеды для следующих учащихся" или "Организовать завтраки и обеды следующим учащимся"

Answer (score 2):

Организовать что? для кого?Первый вариант, на мой взгляд более приемлем, но всё равно не очень удачен.
Если это канцелярско-деловой стиль,есть клише. Организовать можно приём пищи, а завтраками и обедами можно обеспечить учащихся. Если это пункт плана , пишут:организовать горячее питание в группе(классе).Если отчёт:горячим питанием охвачено...человек,если требуются фамилии, то "обеспечить (что?)регулярное горячее питание в виде завтраков и обедов (питание  кого?)следующих учащихся (можно и Обеспечить (что? кому?)следующим учащимся).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Организовать завтраки и обеды для учащихся. Желательно использовать именно этот вариант. Р.п. здесь указывает на предмет, в интересах которого совершается действие (обобщенное значение сопричастности). Также в этом случае мы имеем парное именное словосочетание, в котором главным словом является существительное: "обеды для  учащихся".

Вариант 2. Организовать завтраки и обеды учащимся. Вариант Д.п. грамматически также возможен, но семантически он менее точен. Д.п. имеет значение адресата, то есть мы будем иметь обеды, предназначенные исключительно для школьников, а не просто обеды.

Comment: Интересно сравнить: устроить праздник ребенку (конкретный адресат, Д.п.) и устроить (организовать) праздник для детей (здесь Р.п.  не определяет праздник адресно, а указывает на его предназначенность).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @кудя, у Вас ударение на первом или на втором слоге?